# Symfony 4 won't translate and always shows the English default

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

I'm running Symfony 4 and I installed the translation system using

```
composer require symfony/translation
```

I've create two files in `/translations`:

- *messages.en.xlf*
- *messages.es.xlf*

Using `php bin/console debug:translation es` I also get the correct result:

```
----------- ---------- ------ ---------------------- ------------------------------- 
 State       Domain     Id     Message Preview (es)   Fallback Message Preview (en)  
----------- ---------- ------ ---------------------- ------------------------------- 
             messages   test   Value ES               Value EN                       
----------- ---------- ------ ---------------------- -------------------------------
```

The entries look like this:

```
<trans-unit id="test">
    <source>test</source>
    <target>Value EN</target>
</trans-unit>
```

and this:

```
<trans-unit id="test">
    <source>test</source>
    <target>Value ES</target>
</trans-unit>
```

---

In my controller I set the locale, which seems to work fine and is also represented in the Twig templates:

```
public function index(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $request->setLocale('es');
    // prints 'es'
    print $request->getLocale();
    return $this->render();
}
```

And in Twig:

```
{# prints 'es' #}
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

---

However, when I now run:

```
print $translator->trans('test');
```

or:

```
{{ 'test'|trans }}
```

I always get `Value EN`, which seems not correct as it should be `Value ES`.

---

I'm running Symfony 4.0 and cleared the cache multiple times - even deleted the whole folder.

The `translations.yml` looks like this:

```
framework:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translator:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - '%locale%'
```

And the `services.yml`looks like this:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    locales: en|de|es
```

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the url for your view?

Comment: It depends as the locale is determined by the URL. So `domain.es` and `domain.en` will set the `locale`. There's no language slug involved in this project. @Med

Comment: If no language slug involved, the answer of Jack Skeletron looks true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html)

> To set the user's locale, you may want to create a custom event
>   listener so that it's set before any other parts of the system (i.e.
>   the translator) need it:

And then (this is the part that explains your code behaviour)

> Setting the locale using $request->setLocale() in the controller is
>   too late to affect the translator. Either set the locale via a
>   listener (like above), the URL (see next) or call setLocale() directly
>   on the translator service.

Comment: Oh boy, I used somehting similar to this in a Symfony 3 project, where the locale was set by the slug. I didn't go this way, as the the locale is set by the domain this time. Thanks a lot, got it working now.

Comment: For me works `KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 101]`, eg event with priority after default locale